# BigQuery: Saving query result to partitioned table using cloud client

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am currently using following client as suggested in BigQuery documentation `com.google.cloud:google-cloud-bigquery:1.36.0`

Looks like specifying time partitioning for destination table is not yet supported in this client. Is this expected or do I need to use old client  `com.google.apis:google-api-services-bigquery` to use this feature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to set specific attributes in the client. Use a [`CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` DDL statement](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data-definition-language#create_table_statement), e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE dataset.new_table
PARTITION BY DATE(timestamp_column) AS
SELECT x, y, z, timestamp_column
FROM dataset.existing_table
```